# Windsor Dependency Injection Problem with generics

Tags: castle-windsor

I have an Interface `IRepo <Entity>`. I have a generic implementation `Repo<Entity>`.
Now i just do the following

Container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("assemblyname").Pick()
                                  .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                                  .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest))

and register all the interface with respective implementations. This seems to work fine.

My Problem arises when i try to be more specific.
If i try to map `IRepo<Person>` with Person being a class subclassing Entity with `<UserRepo>` using

Container.Register(Component.For(`IRepo<Person>`).ImplementedBy(UserRepo).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

It does not seem to work.

The order in which i am doing this is that i am registering this specific implementation and then loading and registering all the interfaces to types from the assembly.

It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultInterface` doesn't support generics. You can use `AllInterfaces` instead or a custom strategy via `Select` method

Comment: i use using Container.Register(typeof(IRepo<Person>), typeof(UserRepositry)); and then doing Container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("assemblyname").Pick() .WithService.AllInterfaces() .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest)). Still no luck :(

Comment: ok i finally resolved it. I forgot to mention override in the functions of the implemented subclass. Now Windsor maps according to the generic type.